# Unreachable code, but without any warning

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

After almost an hour of debugging, I finally discover missing semicolon after one return statement. Here is simplified version

```
void PrintNumber(int value) {
    cout << value << endl;
}

void BuggyFunction(int value)
{
    if (value == 0)
        return

    PrintNumber(value);
}
```

Yeah, PrintNumber will never be called. But compiler (VS 2015) was silent. Is there a reason for this behaviour?

Comment: Well, PrintNumber will be called if the value is zero. I think visual studio only analyzes the current method, you would need a whole program analysis to figure this out

Comment: Nice logical bug (Valid code, however)

Comment: You'll save that hour in the future if you use square brackets in every if statement.

Comment: @DanielDaranas Square [, Round (, Curly {

Comment: @Dieter Thank you! Unfortunately, the 5 minutes have just expired and I cannot edit my comment.

Comment: @DanielDaranas You probably meant `{}` braces. Square brackets are `[]` IIRC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, technically your function is (due to the missing semicolon) interpreted as follows:

```
void BuggyFunction(int value) {
    if (value == 0) {
      return PrintNumber(value);
    }
}
```

Since `PrintNumber` has also `void` as a return type, this statement is perfectly syntactically legal, although it doesn't make much sense, obviously.

Note that the C++ compiler doesn't care about indentation. If you want to scope statements and variables correctly, use curly brackets (as I did in the above snippet) to avoid confusion.

Comment: Or avoid early returns: `if(value != 0) { PrintNumber(value); } would express the intention better in this simple case.

Comment: GCC 6 actually has a `-Wmisleading-indentation` warning :)

Answer (score 2):

Your code is equivalent to:

```
void BuggyFunction(int value)
{
    if (value == 0)
    {
        return PrintNumber(value);
    }
}
```

Since PrintNumber's return type is void, this does not generate any compiler warning related to suspicious implicit type conversions.

If your compiler generated an "unreachable code" warning, it would be mistaken, since all the code you wrote is reachable.